# Sightly ul tag closing issue AEM

Tags: html-lists, aem, sightly

In Sightly on using ol inside ul tag. All the tags are closing in proper way.

But whene I am using Ul inside ul(nested ul) all tags are closing at the end not in proper place.

So can any one suggest me. How can I use nested ul in Sightly.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet using which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: when  ol is inside ul tag       <ul>
 ITEM_BEGIN
 <li>
  NODE_OPEN
  <ol>
   ITEM_BEGIN
   <li>
   ITEM_END
   </li>
      
  NODE_CLOSE
        </ol>
 ITEM_END
  </li>
  
</ul>                       when  ul is inside ul tag      <ul>
 ITEM_BEGIN
 <li>
  NODE_OPEN
  <ul>
   ITEM_BEGIN
   <li>
   ITEM_END
   </li>
      
  NODE_CLOSE

 ITEM_END
  
 </ul></li>
  
</ul>

Comment: Copy and paste in notepad for get more understanding.

Comment: This is working as expected. The tags are nested properly. I guess there is some sightly scripts / conditions written in your tags which possibly might have caused the issue. It would be better if you can update your question with the actual code.

Comment: Is this a behaviour that when we use nested ul all tags will closed at last?because in ul and ol case </ol> is coming after NODE_CLOSE but in case of ul and ul all tags closing at last.

Comment: No. The expected behaviour is that the tags need to be nested properly. That is, the inner most tag needs to be closed first followed by its outer tags. (Similar to LIFO). And that is how it is working as well.

Answer (score 1):

The mark up is 'correcting itself', that is to say that the li and ul tags close off within the **enclosing div** and hence no closing li of ul tags remain. However any text or self contained tags (tags opened and closed within the div) will show as you might expect.
Consider re-writing the Sightly code so that it wraps around the full `<li>...</li>` or `<ul>...</ul>` e.g. something like

```
 <ul class="level-1">
    <div data-sly-test="${name =='NODE_OPEN'}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <ul class="level-${level}">
              <div data-sly-test="${name =='ITEM_BEGIN'}" data-sly-unwrap>
                <li>
                  <a href=#>${title}</a>
                </li>
              </div>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul class="level-1">
      <div data-sly-test="${name =='NODE_OPEN'}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <ul class="level-${level}">
      </div>
      <div data-sly-test="${name =='ITEM_BEGIN'}" data-sly-unwrap>
        <li>
          <a href=#>${title}</a>
      </div>
      <div data-sly-test="${name =='ITEM_END'}" data-sly-unwrap></li></div>
      <div data-sly-test="${name =='NODE_CLOSE'}" data-sly-unwrap></ul></div>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This is the snapshot of code. In Line  <div data-sly-test="${name =='NODE_CLOSE'}" data-sly-unwrap></ul></div> ...ul tag is not closing but  anything inside this div is printing. Please help me out. Why ul tag is not closing?